# Elasticsearch graph, How to visualize relations between two imported tables (MySQL)

Tags: elasticsearch, graph, elastic-stack

ELK stack version 5.2

**Current situation**

I have imported two database tables into indexes (users and movies):

*Users:*
user_id, name, movie_id

*Movies:*
movie_id, title

GET /users/user/1 and GET /movies/movie/1 can be done.

**What I want to achieve**

I want to generate a graph that visualizes the connections between these indexes.

**Questions**

Can this be done by two indexes?

Is there a greater solution by creating one index that holds users with an array of movies?

Comment: You can query multiple indexes(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html) and do an aggregation(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html) on the result. I think  this would be a good start to achieve what you are looking for.

If you have some code might be easier to help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, is it possible to create an index that uses that techniques on other indexes? Graph expects an index...